# Get table group's min element in sql

Tags: sql

I want to get retrieve who has min salary in every group.
Here is employees table:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID FIRST_NAME               SALARY
------------- -------------------- ----------
       90      Steven                    24000
       90      Neena                     17000
       90      Lex                       17000
       60      Alexander                  9000
       60      Bruce                      6000
       60      Diana                      4200
       50      Kevin                      5800
       50      Trenna                     3500
       50      Curtis                     3100
       50      Randall                    2600
       50      Peter                      2500
```

For example, I want to retrieve people [Lex, Diana, Peter] in group [90, 60, 50] who has min salary, how to do it?

Platform: win10

Sql version: sqldeveloper 18.1

Comment: Add a tag of your database system and its version

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thanks.

Comment: Neena "has min salary" too.  Why are you excluding her ?

Comment: @ErwinSmout Aha! I ignore her...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by dept_id order by sal) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

However, if the `row_number()` is not help then use correlated subquery instead :

```
select t.*
from table t
where sal = (select min(t1.sal)
             from table t1
             where t1.dept_id = t.dept_id
            );
```

The result would be different if the same department has same minimum salary with other employee, the first version would give you only one row for each department while second would be give you one or more rows for each department.

Comment: Fast response and perfect answer. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: And you might have added that the row_number version is not guaranteed to return the same row on distinct invocations even if the input hasn't changed.

Comment: In many cases, the "best way" is not `row_number()`, but the correlated subquery -- if by "best" you mean fastest.  This, of course, needs to be tested on a particular data on a particular system, but the correlated subquery can be fastest.